# Populating datatable with json from an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, datatable

I cant seem to get my data into my datatable:

I have an input field and a button. When i press the button i want to populate my datatable with the specific data from the API.

Function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "https://cvrapi.dk/api?search="+$('#cvrInput').val()+"&country=dk",
        dataSrc : ''
    },
    "columns" :  [
       {data : "vat"}
    ,
       {data : "name"}
    ,    
       {data : "address"}
    ]
 });
});
```

});

The api is called correctly, but the table is not filled.

Table html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>CVR</th>
         <th>Navn</th>
         <th>Adresse</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTable with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023879/datatable-with-json-data)

Comment: The data you want to show is located in `{ productionunits : [..] }` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are converting ajax response into plain array see document commenting here

> Get JSON data from a file via Ajax, using dataSrc to read data from a
>   plain array rather than an array in an object:

i think you just need a URL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : "https://cvrapi.dk/api?search="+$('#cvrInput').val()+"&country=dk",
   });
  });
});
```

see example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)

Comment: Okay - I tried this, and now it complains in the datatables.js. The api returns a single json object, how can i chose the 3 things i want from this and display in the table ?

Comment: thn i will suggest first fetch data from ajax then select 3 thing make an array of object and bind it to datatable

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. The json is super simple: https://cvrapi.dk/api?search=30829689&country=dk . I just want the three first things to be in my datatable

Comment: see your example here what i am talking about https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/3uodhxtr/9/

Comment: Thank you very much! The jsfiddle link made me understand the logic - and i can now do what i want with the data i get from the json - Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.